# Pointers and determining data types

Tags: c, pointers

I am confused on how to read general pointer syntax, especially when it starts involving arrays, double asterisk, triple asterisk, etc.

For example:

```
char** a = ...;
*ptr = &a[1];
```

How would you read this? Walking through the logic, what would the final data type of `ptr` be?
Edit: This is not functional code, it's more of an exercise to show an understanding of pointers.

Comment: There must have been an earlier declaration of `ptr` that tells you what its type is. In this code you are using the existing variable `ptr`  (as evinced by the fact that there is no type name mentioned)

Comment: OK but that doesn't change the answer (which is: the type of `ptr` is determined by its declaration, which you haven't shown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start off, `a` is of type `char**`, or "a pointer to a pointer to a character". Depending on your context, this could also conceptually be treated as a pointer to a c-string or an array of c-strings.

`a[1]` treats `a` as an array and gets the item in index 1 (the second item, as 0 is the first). This value is of type `char*` (a pointer to a character or array) is located one after the the value that `a` points to.

`&a[1]` gives you a reference to `a[1]`. This means that it gives you a pointer value (`char**` in this case) pointing to the memory containing `a[1]`.

`*ptr =` dereferences the `ptr` location and sets it to the value on the right hand side of the expression. Because `&a[1]` is of type `char**`, then `*ptr` is *probably* of type `char**` too, though it might not be (which could be undesirable).

If `*ptr` is of type `char**`, then `ptr` is of type `char***`. The semantic meaning of this code can differ based on the context and what you are trying to accomplish, but my best guess is that `a` is an array of strings, and `ptr` is getting set to point to the second element of the array. Keep in mind that the second element of the array is a pointer, and `ptr` does not point to what this pointer points to, but the actual location of the pointer itself.

Here's pseudocoded explanation with a list of strings:

```
a = ["apple", "pear", "banana"]
```

After running the code...

```
ptr = ["pear", "banana"]
```

Where the objects pointed to by `ptr` are they *same* as `a`, and you are merely looking at a "subview" of `a`'s list.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.